# Deciding which implementation to inject

Tags: spring, dependency-injection

I have a Spring project, split into several modules.

1. data access library (spring-data-jpa; entities and repositories)
2. security library (spring-security; including an extended repository with @PreAuthorize annotations)
3. web project (depends on both libraries)
4. batch project (depends only on data, since there's no user to authenticate in Spring)

So in the data access library, I have this interface:

```
@Repository
public interface ItemRepository extends PagingAndSortingRepository<Item, Long> {
    List<Item> findAll();
    Item findById(Long id);
}
```

And in the security library:

```
@Repository
public interface SecuredItemRepository extends ItemRepository {

    @PreAuthorize("hasRole('ROLE_ADMIN')")
    List<Item> findAll();

    @PreAuthorize("hasRole('ROLE_ADMIN')")
    Item findById(Long id);
}
```

When I `@Autowire` an `ItemRepository`, I would like it to use `SecuredItemRepository` if it's available, and `ItemRepository` if not.

Is there a way to declare the `SecuredItemRepository` as the default choice, or first in the list of ItemRepository implementations to grab? I'd rather not specify the implementation in every location that I need to access the database.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

And of course, two seconds later I find the answer. I needed to annotate `SecuredItemRepository` with this:

```
@Priority(value = Ordered.HIGHEST_PRECEDENCE)
```